# Почему куда-то мылятся?

Tags: этимология

"Мылится" в переносном значении — собираться куда-то. А почему так говорят, при чем тут мыло?

Comment: Также: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/437337/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%83-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bc%d1%8b%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%8f%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%b2%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b9-%d1%81%d0%bc%d1%8b%d1%81%d0%bb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По поводу "намылится куда-то" версии следующие:

1. Намыливаться - в смысле человек помылся с мылом перед уходом куда-то. Мыло раньше было дорогим, применялось не всеми и в особо торжественных случаях. Его использование могло говорить о какой-то очень важной встрече.
2. У Даля в словарной статье о мыле есть еще пара слов о том, что в старину подмыливали полозья, подмазывали. Соответственно, перед поездкой, о которой неосведомленный человек мог спросить. (маленький нюанс - ПОДмыленный, а не НАмыленный).

Обе версии, честно говоря, сомнительные, но пусть будут.

И еще вспомнилась взмыленная лошадь. Но здесь другое значение. Оно, кстати, сохраняется в выражении "я весь в мыле" (о человеке, который очень торопился, быстро бежал).

Comment: Версия о полозьях мне кажется более правдоподобной

Answer (score 2):

Мне кажется, что все несколько проще.
Если намылился - то хочешь - не хочешь, а смывать придется. Иначе в парную не пустят.
Это подтверждается еще и тем, что идиома сия используется обычно в контексте "намылился было, а тут бац - и вторая смена".

А насчет полозьев... Ахронизм какой-то. Выражение, как я понимаю, довольно молодое, уже советской эпохи. Какие уж тут полозья...

Answer (score -1):

Не забываем о времени, когда очень узкие штаны, перед выходом из дома, приходилось одевать с мылом!!