# Как у слова "намылиться" появился второй смысл?

Tags: этимология, значение-слов, жаргон

> Намылиться — люсь, лишься; св. (нсв. мылиться). 1. Намылить себя. Тщательно н. Намылься ещё раз. Н. банным мылом. 2. (с инф). Разг. сниж. Собраться, вознамериться уехать куда л. Н. уехать. Н. в Америку. Он уже намылился и дом продал. ◁ Намыливаться, аюсь, -аешься; нсв. [Энциклопедический словарь](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/es/115285/%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F)

Почему *намылился* означает *собрался*? Почему собрался именно уехать (так говорит словарь)?

Comment: Такой вопрос уже был: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/27342/Почему-куда-то-мылятся. Мне кажется, что надо их объединить .

Answer (score 3):

У Даля находим выражение "подмылить полозья" (т.е. намазать их для лучшего скольжения". В современном языке - "намылить лыжи", выступающее также в переносном смысле, в качестве фразеологизма. Значение "собрался уехать" у слова "намылился" можно рассматривать как результат этой ассоциации и своеобразного свертывания фразеологизма.

Answer (score 2):

В "Этимологическом словаре славянских языков" О.Н.Трубачёва в статье "мылиться" зафиксировано одно из диалектных значений:

> намереваться, пытаться что-либо сделать (смол., пск.)

В толковом словаре языковых изменений конца XX в. под редакцией В.Г. Скляровской оно значится в качестве жаргонного: "намылиться — собираться что-либо сделать".

Если эти значения как-то связаны, то история слова уходит в глубину веков.